# open()/f.write() not working once python is "compiled" using py2app

Tags: python, file-io, tkinter, fwrite, py2app

Using `py2app` to convert `.py` to `.app`. At first, it looks fine but when I go to execute `open()` and `f.write` (as below) to create a `.txt` it won't create the file.

```
f = open(name + ".txt", "w")
f.write("users inputs here")
```

This works absolutely fine when I run the program as `.py`

Anyone got any ideas, I can't seem to find anything out there that explains why this is happening.

Comment: Are you using relative or absolute paths?

Comment: *it wont create the file*: did you get an error message?

Comment: no error messages when I run as .py or .app, and the path is relative I think i.e i want it to reate the txt file in the same directory that the .app is in

Comment: I am also having this problem. I believe it has something to do with the encoding of the files. When I try to open .py files I edited with emacs they open fine, but a text file downloaded from the internet (UTF-8 encoding) does not work. When I go into the contents of the app created from py2app and run the executable file stored there, it runs fine and I can open files. My system setup has several versions of Python. I run python3.3 setup.py py2app to create my app, but I have a suspicion that somehow code from python2.x is getting in there even though I don't see any in my py2app output.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the current directory is set to `/` when an app is launched from the Finder. Therefore, paths are relative to `/`, instead of your app bundle.

To get the path to the Python exe, try `sys.executable`. Note that you may need to add `../../` to get out of the `Contents/MacOS` directory.

However, a better solution might be to simply use a file dialog, allowing the user to choose the save location.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with my program where I am opening a file and writing column headers into that file, then later in the program iterating data into it in a loop. When the app was converted to a .app, the program would fail when it reached the write column headers to file. If I commented it out, it would work fine. I deleted all special characters from the text in the column headers and it worked fine. Not sure why this is.

doesn't work:

```
file.write("\n" + "Image" + "\t" + "x (pxl)" + "\t" + "y (pxl)" + "\t" + "radius (ID; µm)" + "\t" + "GlobalThresh Reported:" + "\n")
```

works:

```
file.write("\n" + "Image" + "\t" + "x" + "\t" + "y" + "\t" + "radius" + "\t" + "GlobalThresh Reported" + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

A practical solution that implements sys.executable, as @nneonneo states can be this one; it works for me:

```
location = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(sys.executable + "/file_name", '..', '..', '..', '..','..', "file_name"))
```

it prints the file one level exactly above the .app folder

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

Launching */dist/Appname.app/Contents/MacOS/Appname* the app behaves normally: Opens file, truncates file, writes new content to file and then closes it.

Launching the app itself somehow failed with `open(file=os.path.expanduser(outputPath), mode="w")` and just produced an empty file.

Adding `encoding="utf-8"` to the `open` statement solved that.

I only noticed when looking at the `open as` object I was using – all of a sudden it said `encoding='US-ASCII'`